# PDFLatex does not find beamer template

Tags: beamer

I have written one customized beamer template (it consists of multiple files). I pushed it on github and now I want to use it as a git submodule in another git project.

The beamer template works fine if the .tex file and all the .sty files are in the same directory, but if I use it in a submodule not, because the compiler (pdflatex) does not find the sty files. This is the tree of the directory:

[image]

In particular the `beamercolorthemepadua.sty` file includes the other ones with the following latex code:

```
\usepackage{mycolor}
\useinnertheme{padua}
\useoutertheme{padua}
\usecolortheme{padua}
```

The `main.tex` file includes the beamer template with the following latex instructions:

```
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usepackage{YAUBT/beamerthemepadua} 
}
```

Now if I compile the `main.tex` file from the root directory of the project,
that includes the beamertemplate in the subdirecotry the compiler (`pdflatex` and `latexmk`) does not succeed because:

[image]

That makes sense because the files are not in the same directory in which the compiler works.

How can I say to LaTeX that it should search in the subdirectories?

I tried also to modify the `TEXINPUTS` variables, but without success.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try for `TEXINPUTS`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I re-tried now with the following `export TEXINPUTS=.:$PWD/YAUBT:$TEXINPUTS` and it works, but now I cannot import the images. `LaTeX Warning: File `./img/big_logo.png' not found on input line 94.`

Comment: Try `TEXINPUTS=.:$PWD/YAUBT//:$TEXINPUTS` (you might have to replace  `./img/big_logo.png` with `big_logo.png` in your theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
TEXINPUTS=.:$PWD/YAUBT//:$TEXINPUTS
```

instead of

```
TEXINPUTS=.:$PWD/YAUBT:$TEXINPUTS
```

it will not only search the `YAUBT` directory, but also its sub-directories, e.g. `img`, and thus be able to find your images.